# Convert CSV to object array in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Hi I am creating a function that pulls my uploaded CSV via ajax then I would like to form an json object that can be posted to the woocommerce API.

The first loop in the while loop creates my labels array and every loop through it is using the labels as a key.

```
        if ($file !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",")) !== FALSE):
//                print_r($data);
                if($row == 1) {
                    $labels = $data;
                } else {
                    $new_data = array_combine($labels, $data);
                    array_push($csv_data, $new_data);
                }
                $row++;
            endwhile;
            foreach($csv_data as $data){
                echo "New Customer:  ";
                print_r($data);

            }
            fclose($file);
        }
```

When I run this code I get this result:

```
New Customer:  Array
(
    [Name] => Test Dude
    [Username] => Test
    [Email] => test@johndeer.com
    [Orders] => 1
    [proceed_id] => 765
    [AOV] => 765
    [Country / Region] => US
    [City] => Testerton
    [Region] => AR
    [Postal Code] => 71601
    [Address] => John Drive
)
New Customer:  Array
(
    [Name] => John Deer
    [Username] => johndeer
    [Email] => johndeer@jonnydeers.com
    [Orders] => 0
    [proceed_id] => 0
    [AOV] => 0
    [Country / Region] => CA
    [City] => Testerton
    [Region] => AB
    [Postal Code] => T6M 2V5
    [Address] => John Street
)
New Customer:  Array
(
    [Name] => John Doe
    [Username] => john.doe
    [Email] => john.doe@example.com
    [Orders] => 0
    [proceed_id] => 0
    [AOV] => 0
    [Country / Region] => US
    [City] => San Francisco
    [Region] => CA
    [Postal Code] => 94103
    [Address] => John Drive
)
New Customer:  Array
(
    [Name] => John Doe
    [Username] => johndoe
    [Email] => johndoe@example.com
    [Orders] => 0
    [proceed_id] => 0
    [AOV] => 0
    [Country / Region] => US
    [City] => San Francisco
    [Region] => CA
    [Postal Code] => 94103
    [Address] => 
)
New Customer:  Array
(
    [Name] => John Doe
    [Username] => johndoe1
    [Email] => johndoe123@example.com
    [Orders] => 0
    [proceed_id] => 0
    [AOV] => 0
    [Country / Region] => US
    [City] => San Francisco
    [Region] => CA
    [Postal Code] => 94103
    [Address] => 
)
New Customer:  Array
(
    [Name] => John Doe
    [Username] => johndoe7
    [Email] => johndoe1234@example.com
    [Orders] => 0
    [proceed_id] => 0
    [AOV] => 0
    [Country / Region] => US
    [City] => San Francisco
    [Region] => CA
    [Postal Code] => 94103
    [Address] => 
)
New Customer:  Array
(
    [Name] => John Doe
    [Username] => johndoe5
    [Email] => johndoe5@example.com
    [Orders] => 0
    [proceed_id] => 0
    [AOV] => 0
    [Country / Region] => US
    [City] => San Francisco
    [Region] => CA
    [Postal Code] => 94103
    [Address] => 
)
New Customer:  Array
(
    [Name] => John Doe
    [Username] => johndoe6
    [Email] => johndoe6@example.com
    [Orders] => 0
    [proceed_id] => 0
    [AOV] => 0
    [Country / Region] => US
    [City] => San Francisco
    [Region] => CA
    [Postal Code] => 94103
    [Address] => 
)
New Customer:  Array
(
    [Name] => John Doe
    [Username] => johndoe8
    [Email] => johndoe8@example.com
    [Orders] => 0
    [proceed_id] => 0
    [AOV] => 0
    [Country / Region] => US
    [City] => San Francisco
    [Region] => CA
    [Postal Code] => 94103
    [Address] => 
)
0
```

It displays **New Customer:** in each loop just to show that is one loop cycle. However when I try to select "Name" or "proceed_id" it returns null. I've tried to use both of these syntaxes `$data['Name]` and `$data->Name`. How do I select by key inside this foreach?

```
            foreach($csv_data as $data){
                //$data is the individual rows
                $proceed_id = $data['proceed_id']; 
            }
```

EDIT 1:

Here is the vardump of $csv_data outside loop.

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  array(11) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(9) "Test Dude"
    ["Username"]=>
    string(4) "Test"
    ["Email"]=>
    string(17) "test@johndeer.com"
    ["Orders"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["proceed_id"]=>
    string(3) "765"
    ["AOV"]=>
    string(3) "765"
    ["Country / Region"]=>
    string(2) "US"
    ["City"]=>
    string(9) "Testerton"
    ["Region"]=>
    string(2) "AR"
    ["Postal Code"]=>
    string(5) "71601"
    ["Address"]=>
    string(10) "John Drive"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(11) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(9) "John Deer"
    ["Username"]=>
    string(8) "johndeer"
    ["Email"]=>
    string(23) "johndeer@jonnydeers.com"
    ["Orders"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["proceed_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["AOV"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["Country / Region"]=>
    string(2) "CA"
    ["City"]=>
    string(9) "Testerton"
    ["Region"]=>
    string(2) "AB"
    ["Postal Code"]=>
    string(7) "T6M 2V5"
    ["Address"]=>
    string(11) "John Street"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(11) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(8) "John Doe"
    ["Username"]=>
    string(8) "john.doe"
    ["Email"]=>
    string(20) "john.doe@example.com"
    ["Orders"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["proceed_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["AOV"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["Country / Region"]=>
    string(2) "US"
    ["City"]=>
    string(13) "San Francisco"
    ["Region"]=>
    string(2) "CA"
    ["Postal Code"]=>
    string(5) "94103"
    ["Address"]=>
    string(10) "John Drive"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(11) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(8) "John Doe"
    ["Username"]=>
    string(7) "johndoe"
    ["Email"]=>
    string(19) "johndoe@example.com"
    ["Orders"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["proceed_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["AOV"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["Country / Region"]=>
    string(2) "US"
    ["City"]=>
    string(13) "San Francisco"
    ["Region"]=>
    string(2) "CA"
    ["Postal Code"]=>
    string(5) "94103"
    ["Address"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [4]=>
  array(11) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(8) "John Doe"
    ["Username"]=>
    string(8) "johndoe1"
    ["Email"]=>
    string(22) "johndoe123@example.com"
    ["Orders"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["proceed_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["AOV"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["Country / Region"]=>
    string(2) "US"
    ["City"]=>
    string(13) "San Francisco"
    ["Region"]=>
    string(2) "CA"
    ["Postal Code"]=>
    string(5) "94103"
    ["Address"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [5]=>
  array(11) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(8) "John Doe"
    ["Username"]=>
    string(8) "johndoe7"
    ["Email"]=>
    string(23) "johndoe1234@example.com"
    ["Orders"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["proceed_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["AOV"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["Country / Region"]=>
    string(2) "US"
    ["City"]=>
    string(13) "San Francisco"
    ["Region"]=>
    string(2) "CA"
    ["Postal Code"]=>
    string(5) "94103"
    ["Address"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [6]=>
  array(11) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(8) "John Doe"
    ["Username"]=>
    string(8) "johndoe5"
    ["Email"]=>
    string(20) "johndoe5@example.com"
    ["Orders"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["proceed_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["AOV"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["Country / Region"]=>
    string(2) "US"
    ["City"]=>
    string(13) "San Francisco"
    ["Region"]=>
    string(2) "CA"
    ["Postal Code"]=>
    string(5) "94103"
    ["Address"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [7]=>
  array(11) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(8) "John Doe"
    ["Username"]=>
    string(8) "johndoe6"
    ["Email"]=>
    string(20) "johndoe6@example.com"
    ["Orders"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["proceed_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["AOV"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["Country / Region"]=>
    string(2) "US"
    ["City"]=>
    string(13) "San Francisco"
    ["Region"]=>
    string(2) "CA"
    ["Postal Code"]=>
    string(5) "94103"
    ["Address"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [8]=>
  array(11) {
    ["Name"]=>
    string(8) "John Doe"
    ["Username"]=>
    string(8) "johndoe8"
    ["Email"]=>
    string(20) "johndoe8@example.com"
    ["Orders"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["proceed_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["AOV"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["Country / Region"]=>
    string(2) "US"
    ["City"]=>
    string(13) "San Francisco"
    ["Region"]=>
    string(2) "CA"
    ["Postal Code"]=>
    string(5) "94103"
    ["Address"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
0
```

Var_export() =

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Name' => 'Test Dude',
    'Username' => 'Test',
    'Email' => 'test@johndeer.com',
    'Orders' => '1',
    'proceed_id' => '765',
    'AOV' => '765',
    'Country / Region' => 'US',
    'City' => 'Testerton',
    'Region' => 'AR',
    'Postal Code' => '71601',
    'Address' => 'John Drive',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Name' => 'John Deer',
    'Username' => 'johndeer',
    'Email' => 'johndeer@jonnydeers.com',
    'Orders' => '0',
    'proceed_id' => '0',
    'AOV' => '0',
    'Country / Region' => 'CA',
    'City' => 'Testerton',
    'Region' => 'AB',
    'Postal Code' => 'T6M 2V5',
    'Address' => 'John Street',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'Name' => 'John Doe',
    'Username' => 'john.doe',
    'Email' => 'john.doe@example.com',
    'Orders' => '0',
    'proceed_id' => '0',
    'AOV' => '0',
    'Country / Region' => 'US',
    'City' => 'San Francisco',
    'Region' => 'CA',
    'Postal Code' => '94103',
    'Address' => 'John Drive',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'Name' => 'John Doe',
    'Username' => 'johndoe',
    'Email' => 'johndoe@example.com',
    'Orders' => '0',
    'proceed_id' => '0',
    'AOV' => '0',
    'Country / Region' => 'US',
    'City' => 'San Francisco',
    'Region' => 'CA',
    'Postal Code' => '94103',
    'Address' => '',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'Name' => 'John Doe',
    'Username' => 'johndoe1',
    'Email' => 'johndoe123@example.com',
    'Orders' => '0',
    'proceed_id' => '0',
    'AOV' => '0',
    'Country / Region' => 'US',
    'City' => 'San Francisco',
    'Region' => 'CA',
    'Postal Code' => '94103',
    'Address' => '',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'Name' => 'John Doe',
    'Username' => 'johndoe7',
    'Email' => 'johndoe1234@example.com',
    'Orders' => '0',
    'proceed_id' => '0',
    'AOV' => '0',
    'Country / Region' => 'US',
    'City' => 'San Francisco',
    'Region' => 'CA',
    'Postal Code' => '94103',
    'Address' => '',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'Name' => 'John Doe',
    'Username' => 'johndoe5',
    'Email' => 'johndoe5@example.com',
    'Orders' => '0',
    'proceed_id' => '0',
    'AOV' => '0',
    'Country / Region' => 'US',
    'City' => 'San Francisco',
    'Region' => 'CA',
    'Postal Code' => '94103',
    'Address' => '',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'Name' => 'John Doe',
    'Username' => 'johndoe6',
    'Email' => 'johndoe6@example.com',
    'Orders' => '0',
    'proceed_id' => '0',
    'AOV' => '0',
    'Country / Region' => 'US',
    'City' => 'San Francisco',
    'Region' => 'CA',
    'Postal Code' => '94103',
    'Address' => '',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'Name' => 'John Doe',
    'Username' => 'johndoe8',
    'Email' => 'johndoe8@example.com',
    'Orders' => '0',
    'proceed_id' => '0',
    'AOV' => '0',
    'Country / Region' => 'US',
    'City' => 'San Francisco',
    'Region' => 'CA',
    'Postal Code' => '94103',
    'Address' => '',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Can you please arrange a jsfiddle or a snippet? even with 4-5 lines of CSV data in the code and not in a separated file.

Comment: This should work. What does `var_dump($csv_data);` (outside the loop) say?

Comment: @OfirBaruch I can't make a JSfiddle example as this is on the PHP side.

Comment: If you can add an example for the data in the CSV file it would be good enough - so we'll be able to reproducde it.

Comment: @OfirBaruch Okay I will add the CSV file.

Comment: @ArSeN I have added the vardump to the question.

Comment: Still looks like it should be working. Can you change it to a `var_export()` so we can simply reproduce it?

Comment: @ArSeN I tried print_r($data['Name']) instead of print $data['Name'] or echo $data['Name'] and it returned. I don't understand why. It's a string. I should be able to echo it. Posted the var_export() into the edit

Comment: It seems to be working now. I didn't change any code. But now it seems to be working. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Don't worry, we all learn from experience :)